# Oracle manage historical info and new entries

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which fetches refreshed data on a weekly basis. I would like to add the new data to a table containing the historical records, and also identify if the entries are new or not.

Example:

table 1:

```
col  value
---  -----
c1      v1
c2      v1
c5      v5
```

table 1 hist:

```
date           col  value  new_entry
----           ---  -----  ---------
02/06/2021     c1      v1         NO
02/06/2021     c2      v2         NO
02/06/2021     c3      v3        YES
01/06/2021     c1      v1        YES
01/06/2021     c2      v2        YES
01/06/2021     c4      v4        YES
```

Expected output:

```
date           col  value  new_entry   explanation
----           ---  -----  ---------   -----------
03/06/2021     c1      v1         NO   C1 entry already existed on 02/06/2021
03/06/2021     c2      v2         NO   C2 entry already existed on 02/06/2021
03/06/2021     c5      v5        YES   C5 entry did not exist on 02/06/2021
02/06/2021     c1      v1         NO   C1 entry already existed on 01/06/2021
02/06/2021     c2      v2         NO   C2 entry already existed on 01/06/2021
02/06/2021     c3      v3        YES   C3 entry did not exist on 01/06/2021
01/06/2021     c1      v1        YES   First c1 entry ever
01/06/2021     c2      v2        YES   First c2 entry ever
01/06/2021     c4      v4        YES   First c4 entry ever
```

Comment: the logic is not clear , provide a clear explanation for your desired output

Comment: @eshirvana please find my explanation added on my expected output.

Comment: still not clear , for example c5 , v5   didn't exists on 01/06/2021  nor 02/06/2021

Comment: I would like to just compare the previous day. C5 did not exist on 02/06/2021, that's why I'm taking it as new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first select the rows from `table1` adding date column separately and having value of new_entry with subquery from `table1_hist` then use `union all` to combine the result with existing rows for `table1_hist`.

```
 create table table1(col varchar(50),  value varchar(50));
 insert into table1 values('c1',      'v1');
 insert into table1 values('c2',      'v1');
 insert into table1 values('c5',      'v5');     
 
 create table table1_hist(dates date, col varchar(50),  value varchar(50),  new_entry varchar(50));
 insert into table1_hist values(date '2021-06-02',     'c1',      'v1',         'NO');
 insert into table1_hist values(date '2021-06-02',     'c2',      'v2',         'NO');
 insert into table1_hist values(date '2021-06-02',     'c3',      'v3',        'YES');
 insert into table1_hist values(date '2021-06-01',     'c1',      'v1',        'YES');
 insert into table1_hist values(date '2021-06-01',     'c2',      'v2',        'YES');
 insert into table1_hist values(date '2021-06-01',     'c4',      'v4',        'YES');
```

Query:

```
 select date '2021-06-03' dates,col,value,
 (case when exists(select 1 from table1_hist th where th.col=t.col)  then 'NO' else 'YES' end )new_entry
 from table1 t
 union all
 select * from table1_hist
```

### Output:

| DATES | COL | VALUE | NEW_ENTRY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03-JUN-21 | c1 | v1 | NO |
| 03-JUN-21 | c2 | v1 | NO |
| 03-JUN-21 | c5 | v5 | YES |
| 02-JUN-21 | c1 | v1 | NO |
| 02-JUN-21 | c2 | v2 | NO |
| 02-JUN-21 | c3 | v3 | YES |
| 01-JUN-21 | c1 | v1 | YES |
| 01-JUN-21 | c2 | v2 | YES |
| 01-JUN-21 | c4 | v4 | YES |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7667d6f5c9643512d96f64dc43e7e750)*